# Using a singleton to store data from servlets (using jetty)

Tags: java, singleton, jetty

I am implementing a server client project.

I am using Jetty on the server side.

I want to store each client's connect time whenever a client connects (via http) to server in some kind of shared location place.

I chose `map` `<clientID, ClinetInfo>` and I used a singelton to store all the data.

unfortunately, that doesn't work.. the singleton object is created new each time a client sends http request and the jetty handle is triggered.

Why?

How can I implement this persistence of all the clients information?

I attache the code (please ignore the logic of handling the reuqest.. it is not relavent).

```
package com.server;

import com.server.client.ClientsVisitsSingleton;
import com.server.httphandlers.RequestsHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;

public class ProtectingServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(8081);

        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setResourceBase(".");
        context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        server.setHandler(context);
        ClientsVisitsSingleton.getInstance();
        context.setHandler(new RequestsHandler());

        server.start();
        server.join();

        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

RequestsHandler

```
package com.server.httphandlers;

import com.server.client.ClientUtils;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RequestsHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=utf-8";


    @Override
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException

    {


        if (ClientUtils.isClientRequest(request)) {
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
//here is where I used the singlton object to store the client access time.. which instantiate an new object instead using the singlton.
            clientHandler.handleClientAccess(request, response);
        }
        else{
            response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);

    }


}
```

Singleton Object

```
package com.server.client;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ClientsVisitsSingleton {
    private static ClientsVisitsSingleton clientsVisitsSingleton;
    private Map<Long, ClientVisitsInfo> clientsVisits;

    private ClientsVisitsSingleton() {
        clientsVisits = new HashMap<Long, ClientVisitsInfo>();
    }

    public static synchronized ClientsVisitsSingleton getInstance() {
        if (clientsVisitsSingleton == null) {
            synchronized (ClientsVisitsSingleton.class) {
                if (clientsVisitsSingleton == null) {
                    clientsVisitsSingleton = new ClientsVisitsSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return clientsVisitsSingleton;
    }

    public Map<Long, ClientVisitsInfo> getClientsVisits() {
        return clientsVisits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception

Comment: change my description. not exception but a new instance of the singlton is bein created

Comment: could you please post the `ClientHandler `. Also note that you are `synchronized ` twice in `ClientsVisitsSingleton.getInstance()` once *on* the method once *in* the method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just ...

```java
ClientsVisitsSingleton singleton = new ClientVisitsSingleton();
context.setHandler(new RequestsHandler(singleton));
```

and then in your `RequestsHandler` ...

```java
public class RequestsHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    final ClientsVisitsSingleton singleton;

    public RequestsHandler(ClientsVisitsSingleton singleton) {
        this.singleton = singleton;
    }

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=utf-8";


    @Override
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        // ... use singleton as any other object here
```

But ultimately, I have to ask, why not just use `ServletContextHandler(SESSIONS)` and use the built-in `HttpSession` concepts already present in Jetty?